# Возможно ли узнать время, прошедшее с момента запуска ОС?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime, ос

Возможно ли узнать время с момента запуска операционки и если да, то как?

Comment: win, unix, osX?

Comment: На win (нужно больше символов)

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

Для **windows** попробуйте:

```
# ctypes required for using GetTickCount64() 
import ctypes 
  
# getting the library in which GetTickCount64() resides 
lib = ctypes.windll.kernel32 
  
# calling the function and storing the return value 
t = lib.GetTickCount64() 
  
# since the time is in milliseconds i.e. 1000 * seconds 
# therefore truncating the value 
t = int(str(t)[:-3]) 
  
# extracting hours, minutes, seconds & days from t 
# variable (which stores total time in seconds) 
mins, sec = divmod(t, 60) 
hour, mins = divmod(mins, 60) 
days, hour = divmod(hour, 24) 
  
# formatting the time in readable form 
# (format = x days, HH:MM:SS) 
print(f"{days} days, {hour:02}:{mins:02}:{sec:02}")
```

Для **unix**:

```
import os 
  
# sending the uptime command as an arguement to popen() 
# and saving the returned result (after truncating the trailing \n) 
t = os.popen('uptime -p').read()[:-1] 
  
print(t)
```

У меня на *Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS* выводит:

```
up 13 hours, 42 minutes
```